# Egg drop problem solution in template meta-programming

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I have implemented a dynamic programming solution of the egg-dropping problem ([this problem](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/puzzles/2-eggs-100-floors-puzzle/), but generalized for any number of eggs and floors):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>

//Optimal sub-structure
//We have K floor and N eggs
//Case1: If egg break of X floor then we have x - 1 floor and N - 1 egg
//Case2: If egg doesn't break at X floor then we have K - X floor and N eggs
//Base Case1: we have 1 egg then answer is K floor
//Base Case2: we have 0 or 1 floor then 0 or 1 is answer

int cache[1234][1234];

int solve(int egg, int floor) {

    if(floor == 0 || floor == 1 || egg == 1)
        return floor;

    if(cache[egg][floor])
        return cache[egg][floor];

    int result = INT_MAX;
    for(int current_floor = 1; current_floor <= floor; ++current_floor) {
        int local = std::max(solve(egg - 1, current_floor - 1), solve(egg, floor - current_floor));
        if(local < result)
            result = local;
    }

    cache[egg][floor] = 1 + result;
    return cache[egg][floor];
}

int main(void) {

    int egg = 0, floor = 0;
    //egg = 2, floor = 10 result = 4
    std::cin >> egg >> floor;
    std::cout << "result is: " << solve(egg, floor) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Now I want to implement this solution in C++ template meta-programming, but I am really not getting how I can use the result variable from the `solve` function to the loop function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

template<int egg, int floor>
struct solve;

template<int current_floor, int egg, int floor>
struct loop {
    static const int r1 = solve<egg - 1, current_floor - 1>::result;
    static const int r2 = solve<egg, floor - current_floor>::result;
    static const int local = r1 > r2 ? r1 : r2;
    //Here I have to compare this local variable to result variable of the
    //solve class and store?
    //In other words I have to implement
    //if(local < result)
    //  result = local 
    loop<current_floor + 1, egg, floor> l;
};

template<int current_floor, int egg>
struct loop<current_floor, current_floor, egg> {
    static const int r1 = solve<egg - 1, current_floor - 1>::result;
    static const int r2 = solve<egg, floor - current_floor>::result;
    static const int local = r1 > r2 ? r1 : r2;
};

template<int egg, int floor>
struct solve {
    static const int result = loop<1, egg, floor>::result + 1;
};

template<int egg>
struct solve<egg, 0> {
    static const int result = 0;
};

template<int floor>
struct solve<1, floor> {
    static const int result = floor;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //main function to check program
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Template metaprogramming is all about rewriting your program to be *functional* instead of *imperative*, and then not worrying about caching since the compiler takes care of that for you. The other important guideline is that the return of a metafunction is a **type** named `type`. Template metaprogramming is about types - anything that isn't a type is just really annoying to have to deal with, so stay in the type world for as long as possible.

So how do we write this *functionally*? Let's look at the loop - which is the only really interesting part of the code:

```
int result = INT_MAX;
for(int current_floor = 1; current_floor <= floor; ++current_floor) {
    int local = std::max(solve(egg - 1, current_floor - 1), solve(egg, floor - current_floor));
    if(local < result)
        result = local;
}
```

Rewriting this in Python as a generator comprehension (even if you don't know Python, hopefully this is clear):

```
result = 1 + min(
           max(solve(egg-1, current-1), solve(egg, floor-current))
           for current in range(1, floor+1)
           )
```

Going from `1` to `floor` is a little more awkward than going from `0` to `floor-1`, so let's just subtract 1 from `current` everywhere:

```
result = 1 + min(
           max(solve(egg-1, current), solve(egg, floor-current-1))
           for current in range(floor)
           )
```

Now, this is the right form for template metaprogramming! So what tools do we need to build this up?

1. A way to iterate from `0` to `floor-1`
2. A way to take the `min` and `max` of lots of things at compile time
3. A way to add one to a type

For the former, we have [`std::make_index_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) and the latter two I will leave as an exercise.

Once we have these things though, we directly translate the generator comprehension into actual template code thanks to the power of unpacking variadic templates:

```
template <int Egg, int Floor, typename = std::make_index_sequence<Floor>>
struct SolveImpl;

template <int Egg, int Floor, size_t... Current>
struct SolveImpl<Egg, Floor, std::index_sequence<Current...>>
{
    using type = add1<                            // result = 1 +
        min<                                      //   min(
            max<                                  //     max(
                Solve<Egg-1, Current>,            //        solve(egg-1, current),
                Solve<Egg, Floor - Current - 1>   //        solve(egg, floor-current-1)
            >...                                  //     ) for current in range(floor)
        >                                         //  )
    >;
};
```

Dealing with the base cases is just a matter of wrapping with [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional):

```
template <int Egg, int Floor>
struct Solve;

/* the SolveImpl code goes here */

template <int Egg, int Floor>
struct Solve
    : std::conditional_t<
            (Floor == 0 || Floor == 1 || Egg == 1),
            int_<Floor>,
            SolveImpl<Egg, Floor>
            >::type
{ };
```

Again, leaving out the base case details where `Floor == 0`, `Floor == 1`, or `Egg == 1` since those are less interesting. As always, with template metaprograms, `static_assert` is your friend:

```
static_assert(Solve<2, 10>::value == 4, "!");
```

Check!